# How to hack a body scale to be used as digital weight measure

Tags: measurement, home-automation

I am looking for help with hacking a typical digital (body) weighing scale to use in a custom application. Is there some internal digital or analog output in body scales to directly get the measured values? How might I go about reading this output?

I thought about connecting the scale with an Arduino, Tinkerbot or Raspberry Pi for further processing, for instance to weigh other stuff and for home automation. I am not looking to build my own body scale from scratch, just adapt one to be able to extract the measured values. Body fat or similar nonsense (which cannot be measured reliably anyway) is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds not too difficult to do what you are proposing, most digital scales use 1, 2 or 4 [strain gauges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge) in a [Wheatstone bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge) configuration to form a [load cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_cell).
This load cell will output a small differential signal which is read by an [Instrumentation Amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier) (InAmp) to amplify and output a single ended signal that can be easily read by an ADC.

So if you have a digital scale, it's just a question of hacking it and tapping this signal to be read by your PIC, Arduino, etc, to be used as you like (send to PC, display...)
As far as I'm aware the R-Pi doesn't have analog inputs available as "standard", and it sounds like complete overkill for this anyway (unless you are using the R-Pi in place of a PC or something)

Comment: Do you know of anyone having hacked a scale this way, maybe even with images? The analog-to-digital converter should not be the problem, but I need to know which signal to measure.

Comment: I did help someone in chat a while back on here who was doing just this. I'm think there are likely to be quite a few examples of doing something like this out there if you do some searching - using "digital scale hack" on Google I found a few examples [this one](http://scanlime.org/2010/01/hacking-a-digital-bathroom-scale/) looks pretty good. If the question gets reopened we can discuss it here.

Comment: Simple solution is to tap into the connections that go to the display. It should be easy to translate the 7 segment data to a kilogram indication. Does require lot of input pins though.

Comment: @jippie - yep, that's another way of doing it, how easy and how many pins depends on the type of display (7-seg would be good as you say) You don't have quite as much control this way though, e.g. you are limited to whatever resolution the display shows.

Comment: @OliGlaser - but little need to 'calibrate' as that is already done in the scale itself.

Comment: @jippie - Yep, you're right - if you are happy with the scale display as it is then grabbing the display data does make your firmware simpler.

Comment: @jipplie: good idea! I just bought a very simple scale with digital kg display. Looks like it has four 7-seg for values up to 199.9. Can I use a simple BCD-to-7-seg decoder the other way round? Four of these plus a BCD-to-binary circuit should give me a digital 11 bit value that could somehow be converted to a serial signal, right?

Comment: @Jakob This was a [NerdKits video tutorial](http://www.nerdkits.com/videos/weighscale/) a few years ago.

Comment: @Jakob - I'd watch the video, try and decide which route you're taking, then give something a go - if you get stuck along the way just open another question and we can help with each part of the problem in detail.